# На что указывает индекс [0] в коде?

Tags: python, list, индексация, индексы

```py
geo_logs = [
        {'visit1': ['Москва', 'Россия']},
        {'visit2': ['Дели', 'Индия']},
        {'visit3': ['Владимир', 'Россия']},
        {'visit4': ['Лиссабон', 'Португалия']},
        {'visit5': ['Париж', 'Франция']},
        {'visit6': ['Лиссабон', 'Португалия']},
        {'visit7': ['Тула', 'Россия']},
        {'visit8': ['Тула', 'Россия']},
        {'visit9': ['Курск', 'Россия']},
        {'visit10': ['Архангельск', 'Россия']}
]
visits_russia = []
for visits in geo_logs:
    if 'Россия' in list(visits.values())[0]:
        visits_russia.append(visits)
print(visits_russia, '\n')
```

Код перебирает словарь и возвращает `visit` если в значении есть `'Россия'`.

**Но я не понимаю что делает этот `[0]`.**
Если этого `0` нет, то не работает ничего. Почему нельзя просто проверить на наличие значение `'Россия'` без указания индекса?

**Спасибо за помощь!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`geo_logs` - список словарей.

`visits` - это конкретный словарь (пример - `{'visit1': ['Москва', 'Россия']}`).

`visits.values()` - это список значений из словаря. Для словаря `{'visit1': ['Москва', 'Россия']}` это будет `[['Москва', 'Россия']]`. То есть у вас значение в словаре уже список, и `values` вернет список списков. В общем случае там может быть много элементов, но у вас в словаре только один, потому и тут будет только один элемент - список `['Москва', 'Россия']`.

`visits.values()[0]` - вернет этот элемент, т.е. `['Москва', 'Россия']`.

`'Россия' in list(visits.values())[0]` - проверяет, входит ли `Россия` в этот список.

Без `[0]` проверка не работает, так как вы проверяете входит ли `'Россия'` в список `[['Москва', 'Россия']]`, что очевидно не так, так как так единственный элемент это список `['Москва', 'Россия']`, а он не равен строке `'Россия'`.

Comment: Супер, спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {'visit1': ['Москва', 'Россия']}
print(list(a.values())[0])
print(list(a.values()))
print(a.values())
```

Попробуйте ввести данный код и поймете, как это работает)
Выведет:

```
['Москва', 'Россия']
[['Москва', 'Россия']]
dict_values([['Москва', 'Россия']])
```

Я думаю понятно почему работает 1 вариант... Индекс 0 просто убирает массив в массиве оставляя один массив. Когда Вы вызываете функцию values, создается массив в который добавляется ещë один массив. И если Вы проверяете наличие России в массиве в котором другой массив, то не находите значение Россия. Надеюсь объяснил понятно)

Answer (score 2):

Метод `values()` возвращает список из значений словаря. У вас это будет список из списков, т.к. по каждому ключу словаря в значении будет список

Я бы рекомендовал отдельным циклом пройтись по спискам из `values`

Пример:

```
geo_logs = [
    {'visit1': ['Москва', 'Россия']},
    {'visit2': ['Дели', 'Индия']},
    {'visit3': ['Владимир', 'Россия']},
    {'visit4': ['Лиссабон', 'Португалия']},
    {'visit5': ['Париж', 'Франция']},
    {'visit6': ['Лиссабон', 'Португалия']},
    {'visit7': ['Тула', 'Россия']},
    {'visit8': ['Тула', 'Россия']},
    {'visit9': ['Курск', 'Россия']},
    {'visit10': ['Архангельск', 'Россия']}
]

visits_russia = []
for visits in geo_logs:
    for countries in visits.values():
        if 'Россия' in countries:
            visits_russia.append(visits)
print(visits_russia, '\n')
```